# Routing is not working in Reactjs + ES6

Tags: javascript, react-router, reactjs, react-routing

When I am clicking on the link "cake" I am getting the error the path is not matched or server is not able to find.

Here is my code for 3 files - Router, Navigation and detail components

Routers.js- component handling the routing

---

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Router, Route , HashHistory , IndexRoute , useRouterHistory} from 'react-router';
import History from 'history';
import {CreateHashHistory} from 'history';
import createBrowserHistory from 'history/lib/createBrowserHistory';
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router';

import Base from './Base.jsx';
import ListDetail from './ListDetail.jsx';

let Routes = 

        <Router history={browserHistory}>
            <Route path="/" component={Base} >
                <Route path="/cake" component= {ListDetail}></Route>

            </Route>
        </Router>

 export default Routes;
```

---

Navigation components - handling the navigaton links

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Link } from 'react-router';


class ContentList extends React.Component {
    render(){
        return(
            <div id="innercontent">
            <h2>What you love?</h2>
            <ul >
                <Link to={'/cake'}>Cakes</Link>
                <Link to={'/icecream'}>icecream</Link>
                <Link to={'/browin'}>browin</Link>
            </ul>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default ContentList;
```

---

Detail Component - Detail page to display

```
import React from 'react';

import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class ListDetail extends React.Component {
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
            <h1>hi Details</h1>


            </div>
        )
    }
}


export default ListDetail;
```

---

Base.JSX

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Header from './header.jsx';
import Footer from './footer.jsx';
import ContentList from './contentList.jsx';
import FormElement from './form.jsx';
import ListDetail from './ListDetail.jsx';

class Base extends React.Component {
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
            <Header name="My Recipe Book"/>
            <section id="content">
            <FormElement />
             <ContentList />
            </section>
            <Footer />
            <ListDetail />
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

### export default Base;

Main.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Routes from './router.jsx';

ReactDOM.render(Routes, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Thanks for the help!!

Comment: Can you post your base.jsx file?

Comment: Added, you can check

Comment: Where do you render {this.props.children}? You should render it inside Base.jsx file.

Comment: worked :) thanks mate

Comment: Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The render function of your base.jsx file should be something like this :

```
render(){
    return(
        <div>
        <Header name="My Recipe Book"/>
        <section id="content">
        <FormElement />
        <ContentList />
         {this.props.children}
        </section>
        <Footer />
        </div>
    )
}
```

Route should be

```
<Route path="cake" component= {ListDetail} />
```

And the link :

```
<Link to="cake">Cakes</Link>
```

You need to render the routes somewhere.

...A single component to be rendered when the route matches the URL. It can be rendered by the parent route component with this.props.children. [Read this.](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md)

```
const routes = (
  <Route path="/" component={App}>
    <Route path="groups" component={Groups} />
    <Route path="users" component={Users} />
  </Route>
)

class App extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        {/* this will be either <Users> or <Groups> */}
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the / in `/cake`, it's already under `/`. Do it like this:

```
<Route path="cake" component={ListDetail} />
```

Comment: Nope this is not helping :(

Answer (score 0):

Try the following, not sure if it would help.
1. Use

```
   var ContentList = React.createClass({})
```

instead of

```
    class ContentList extends React.Component.
```

2. remove the / before 'cake' in your route path.

3. try using

   ```
    var Routes = React.createClass({
     render: function() {
      return (
       <div>
           <Router history={browserHistory}>
   ```

and your updated code instead of let

hope it helps

Comment: It wouldn't make any sense to go back to ES5 if we have ES6, but about the slash, yeah, it might be. That's what I also though of, but an answer was already posted.

Comment: Check what are you passing in your main.js file? Are you passing the router ie, <Routes/> ?

Comment: It should look some thing like   var content = document.getElementById('app')
ReactDOM.render(
    <Routes/>, content);

Answer (score 0):

Does it work with hashHistory ?

To use browserHistory, you need to set up server side rendering.

Here is the tutorial (especially lesson 11 and 13) which helped me understand and set up react-router using browserHistory and server side rendering:
https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-tutorial/tree/master/lessons/

Hope it helps.